# how to find address file in C# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, passwords, mac-address

in my C# windows form project I have challenge I do not know how to coding for it.
I am not coding this parts yet, But I find some solution and I am not sure which one is current or better. Hope you can help me.

In this program, users can select files from their own system to be stored in the database along with their address. Now, if the user, instead of the system, enters the file from the hard drive or flash or any other external hardware into the database. How do I find out where the file is when reading the file so that the program can run it? Because the order of connecting the hardware may be different every time and as a result the address changes and the file cannot be executed. For this purpose, I want to save the MAC address of the device from which the file is read, along with the name and address of the file. Then, when the user executes the file through the program, I first check on which hardware the file is based on the MAC address, and based on that, correct the address of the file and run it. Is this method correct or do you have a better way?
I hope I was able to clearly explain my challenges.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to store passwords anywhere and the answers to your question can get really complicated really fast. I suggest a reasonable middle path for your problem.
Find a random hashing algorthim, you can find a wide collection here:

https://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm

Implement the algorythm in c#. Usually you can find them online already or use existings libraries. Now if the user enters his password hash it and save the hash. Now every time a user enters a password compare the hashes.

Pro:

+You dont store passwords anwhere directly

+Intruders need to know the hashalgorythem and the hash to reverse engineer your password

Con:

-Medium but in my opinion reasonable level of protection for many applications.

Comment: thank you. I know I should encrypt password and your solution is worked. But I am not understand completely. where should I save and hold this encrypted password? in second database, create one table just for one pass text, hold this text with properties of projects or create web api? which on